# Kibana Scripted fields values not getting populated on visualize but are populated during discover

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, scriptedfield

I am using Kibana scripted fields using painless to populate a URL like this:

```
Url Template : https://dummy_url?branch={{value}}&id=abc
Script: 
if (!doc['branch_name'].empty) {
    return (doc['branch_name'].value)
}
```

When I access this scripted field for my index pattern in Discover, the value gets populated correctly and I can access the URL but when I am accessing the same scripted field in "data table" Visualize, the URL is missing the value populated by {{value}}.

Already tried using {{rawValue}} and doc['branch_name.keyword'] but none worked.

Can you please help on how I can populate the scripted field correctly on data table visualize?

I am using Kibana Version, 5.4.1.

The doc has values like this:

```
branch_name

develop
master
release/f1
release/f2
```

[image]